# How to Post threads

Tags: support

How can I post a thread on a Ubuntu forum?  Also, what the hell is a Tag?
I can't even ask a question without going to school for questions.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site.

I'm Tim - I'm happy to help with this question. If you have any more, please comment them below.

First - how to post a thread? Well, you have. This thread will be moved to our meta site - for discussing the main site, but you've managed. Also, because of how we format this site we normally say "Questions and Answers", not threads. Threads are fine, however.

Second - what's a tag? A tag is a way we sort the questions we receive. For example, some users here are experts on [backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/backup), others on the Linux [kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel) and yet more on when you have a fresh [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation). If you tag your question well, it means people who can answer are more likely to see the question.

Finally - a school for asking? We take pride in this site - and we don't want it to turn into Yahoo Answers. We think the best way to do this is to have good quality control - we have automated systems to detect bad posts, and we have community moderation - as you participate here more, you take a part in keeping the site clean by editing, flagging, closing and deleting.

This can be intimidating and off-putting to a new user, but if you stick around you'll realise that the lack of spam is nice, and proper grammar in questions. You may have noticed I edited your question just after you posted it - that's to improve your question and make people want to help. If you put in the effort, they want to as well!

As I said, if you have more questions please ask away in the comments below. I think you might benefit from [reading the tour page](https://askubuntu.com/tour). It takes less than 2 minutes (two-minute school - wow!) and you'll understand our ethos and the way the site works here.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Technically stackexchange does not have *threads* because it is not an open discussion forum... it has *questions* and answers ;)